# Why WebResourceResponse return null in shouldInterceptRequest()?

Tags: android, http, post, webview, response

I'm trying to get a POST response of a request in WebView. Here are my codes.

```
mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (final WebView view, String url) {
        WebResourceResponse w = super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
        Log.i("type", w.getMimeType());
        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
    }
});
```

But the program crashes and the error is w is null. Could anyone tell me why is that or give me any solution to get a POST response of a request in WebView?

Thank you.

Comment: did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: Never mind, found the answer.

Answer (score 2):

`shouldInterceptRequest()` return null, means that no one intercept the request, and the webview will load the origin URL.

if you want to intercept the request, you should make your own `WebResourceResponse` with the information from the URL param.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, it states that "If the return value is null, the WebView will continue to load the resource as usual.". In the case that something should intercept the request, the response is returned by the override method.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView, android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)